# trouble deleting spaces from String

Tags: java, string, replace, appium, removing-whitespace

I am working with appium automation on a native android app

I have a MobileElement that I want to get the text from

```
MobileElement likesElement = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_textview_likes"));
```

And then I have the String

```
String likesVal = likesElement.getText();
```

When I run `System.out.println(likesVal);` it prints:

```
Liked by you and 107 others
```

I need to delete everything but `107` so I can run parseInt on `likesVal`

I have tried

```
likesVal= likesVal.replaceAll("[*a-zA-Z_.-]", "");
likesVal= likesVal.replaceAll(" ", "");
StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(likesVal);
int likes = Integer.parseInt(likesVal);
System.out.println(likes);
```

But I am getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "107 "` on `int likes = Integer.parseInt(likesVal);`

After stripping `likesVal` of everything but numbers, why wasnt the space that comes before "others" in `likesVal` deleted?

After stripping `likesVal` of everything but numbers I need "107" to be printed instead of "107 "

Comment: have you tried using String.trim() after a replaceAll()?

Comment: Just tried it now, same error

Comment: I ran your code as-is and did not get an error - printed 107 as expected - interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a pattern to replace all non-digits (`\\D`). Like,

```
String tmp = "Liked by you and 107 others";
// String likesVal = likesElement.getText().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
String likesVal = tmp.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
int likes = Integer.parseInt(likesVal);
System.out.println(likes);
```

Outputs

```
107
```

as requested.